# Changing Woocommerce "Add to cart" button to "view product" button

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

Trying to change the woocommerce button text from "add to cart" to "read more" and redirect it so that clicking the button takes the user to the individual product page. So far, the link works but all the text on the button says is "Button" when I need it to say "Read More". I'll place the code below, can anyone please tell me what the problem is.

```
/*STEP 1 - REMOVE ADD TO CART BUTTON ON PRODUCT ARCHIVE (SHOP) */

function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');



/*STEP 2 -ADD NEW BUTTON THAT LINKS TO PRODUCT PAGE FOR EACH PRODUCT */

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
global $product;
$link = $product->get_permalink();
echo do_shortcode('<br>[button link="' . esc_attr($link) . '"]Read More[/button]');
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this alternative that will replace add to cart button by a linked button to the product in Shop and archives pages

```
// Replace add to cart button by a linked button to the product in Shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Not needed for variable products
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return $button;

    // Button text here
    $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );

    return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec,I put your code in and the button has disappeared completely? Not sure if I'm putting it in wrong or what

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: If no child theme, you can use the Theme Customizations Plugin by WooCommerce: https://github.com/woocommerce/theme-customisations

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to replace the default “Add to Cart” button with “Read More” (or anything you like) linking to the single product page.

```
// First, remove Add to Cart Button

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

// Second, add View Product Button

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'shop_view_product_button', 10);
function shop_view_product_button() {
global $product;
$link = $product->get_permalink();
echo '<a href="' . $link . '" class="button addtocartbutton">View Product</a>';
}
```

You can add this PHP Snippet at the very bottom of your active child theme (or main theme) functions.php file. [Code Source](https://wptechnic.com/change-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button-view-product/)