# Why woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link doesn't work within WooCommerce blocks?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, storefront

I am creating a site for a friend in Woocommerce using the storefront theme. I have created a child theme and added the below function to the custom functions in functions.php. This is to change the add-to-basket buttons for single products into 'view product' links that point to the product page.

I am using [Changing Woocommerce "Add to cart" button to "view product" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440289/changing-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button-to-view-product-button/49440642#49440642) answer code.

This works great on everywhere intended across the site exept on WooCommerce Blocks (E.g. hand-picked products, top-rated products etc).

Can anyone tell me why and how I would rectify this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug *(I reported that in Github WooCommerce Blocks [opening an issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/issues/3978))*.

For now, instead you can use any [WooCommerce Shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/) in a "paragraph" Block, which works without bugs using [Changing Woocommerce "Add to cart" button to "view product" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440289/changing-woocommerce-add-to-cart-button-to-view-product-button/49440642#49440642), like:

[image]